# How to convert object to set it into >>> stFormData (react Hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have an object (data) how can i put it into setFormData? currently using react-hook-form all the data compiled to one (data) wondering how to destructure and put into setFormData. Can anyone help, please

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
        Swal.fire('Congratulation!', completeFormStep(), 'success');

        setFormData = data // THIS ONE IM NOT SURE HOW TO SET DATA OBJECT TO setFormData for (data)

        console.log(formData); //still nothing all the data return example 'firstname': '' , 'lastName': ''
        console.log(data); //this one return ('firstname': 'One' , 'lastName': 'Punch Man' 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`setFormData` is a function so you need to call it and pass `data` as argument

```
setFormData(data)
```

you can also use the callback form. The callback form will help you to consider previous state before replacing it. Like if your previous state would look like `{firstName:'', lastName:'', country:'XYZ'}` and your form data has only `firstName` and 'lastName`and country is always 'XYZ' then spreading`{...previousState, ...data}`both the object will only replace`firstName`and`lastName`.

```
setFormData(previousState => {...previousState, ...data});
```